# Displaying JBox2D animation in Android?

Tags: android, graphics

So I followed the tutorial at this site: http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/

As interesting as it is, they leave out one section and from their tutorial: How to display the shapes on the device's screen.

I have a MyTouch 3G running Android 1.6 (donut). What control and what events can I take advantage of to display the shapes from the above tutorial? I've hunted around, any tutorials I've found about JBox2D all point back to this tutorial.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am facing the same issue. I have created a view and am drawing all the bodies[] in that but am unable to animate the scene (basic gravity)

Comment: Perhaps you need to invalidate the view? In .Net applications that was the best way to implement animation. Invalidate the view from another thread or something, if that works, please tell me what you did!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this awesome projects
 http://code.google.com/p/androidbox2d/
 http://code.google.com/p/android-opengl-box2d-basics/